# How is $G$ and "$N$ and $G/N$" related?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group and $N$ be a proper normal subgroup of $G$.

What is a relation between "$G$" $\Leftrightarrow$ "$N$ and $G/N$"?

Can we (isomorphically) construct $G$ using $N$ and $G/N$?

Comment: This is the problematic behind "group extensions" see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension

Comment: No, you can't. For example, if you know that both $G/N$ and $N$ are cyclic of order $2$, you cannot determine $G$: it could be the cyclic group of order $4$ or the Klein group.

Comment: What if $G/N$ is simple?

Comment: @groupstruc in the very simple example given by Crostul, $G/N$ is simple.

Answer (score 0):

A general answer would be: no, we can't. This is the [group extension problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension), which is not solved in full generality.

Comment: What if $G/N$ is simple?

Comment: @groupstruc In Crostul's example above, both $N$ and $G/N$ are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is simple.